# Travis CI and npm, how to close node server after it starts

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, automated-tests, travis-ci

I want to test all the dependencies of a project and need to test if a server runs. Once it runs successfully it should close the server and finish the build. Below is my .travis.yml file:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - "stable"

services:
  - mongodb

install:
  - npm install
  - (cd client/ && npm install)

before_script:
  - cd client/

script:
  - npm start
```

I have the following scripts:

```
"start": "concurrently \"node scripts/start.js\" \"node ../bin/www\"",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom"
```

How can I test my project and finish the build after my server runs correctly? Somehow it needs to run npm start and then npm test afterwards, but npm test requires you to type a to run all tests. It runs npm start which starts the server but waits and cannot exit for npm test to run.

Comment: please post your package json. if you cant post the entire package json. then post the scripts part.

EDit : nevermind.

Comment: Were you able to find a way to stop server?

Comment: @Gorgon_Union no

Answer (score 0):

what you are describing is unit testing the application start. That's not how it works.
You can set up tests to check different aspects of your server, even the application start, but they are run as "tests" not the actual application.

You can even test different routes.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently facing this issue on my travis.yml file.
This Answer doesn't cover how to close server but it has other information which may helpful someway.
It may take a while to start your server on Travis environment. Wait until your server starts

> sleep 30 (Generally it takes more than 15-20 secs)

Try `npm start &`, here ampersand '&' run your server in the background mode. So, you may not need to close it.

Hope this may help others.